# Adding numbers found in a Json object

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, loops

I have a Json object that I am parsing and then comparing to another array to find where they match. I have the code to this point,

```
var gpaGrades = '{"A": 4, "A-": 3.67, "B+": 3.33, "B": 3, "B-": 2.67, "C+": 2.33, "C": 2, "C-": 1.67, "D+": 1.33, "D": 1, "D-": 0.67, "F":0}';
var letterGrades = ["A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "D-"]

var fallGrades = ["Fall 2015", "A-", "B+", "A", "B", "A"];
var springGrades = ["Spring 2016", "A+", "A+", "A-", "B+", "A"];

var gpa = JSON.parse(gpaGrades);
var sum = 0;
function getGrades(semester){
if(semester === "Fall 2015"){
   for (var i = 1; i < fallGrades.length; i++) { 
        for(var x = 0; x < letterGrades.length; x++){
            if (letterGrades[x].indexOf(fallGrades[i]) >= 0) {
                var getGPA = fallGrades[i];
                console.log(gpa[getGPA]);
            }   
        }
    }
}
}
```

This works and gives me all the values that match the letter grades and their corresponding point values.  The problem is I need to get a sum of the gpa[getGPA] values to then calculate the GPA for that semester that I will then divide by the length.

I have tried

```
var sum += gpa[getGPA];
```

Not sure why this won't work as I saw a similar example with just an array of ints working fine.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: take the `var` out of `var sum += gpa[getGPA]; ` , sum is already defined before function, https://jsfiddle.net/jy5xrs92/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use var inside the loop, this re-declares sum each time. Use var outside the loops (should still work inside the function). And then use  `sum += gpa[getGPA];` inside the loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var getGPA =0.0;
    function getGrades(semester){
    if(semester === "Fall 2015"){
       for (var i = 1; i < fallGrades.length; i++) { 
            for(var x = 0; x < letterGrades.length; x++){
                if (letterGrades[x].indexOf(fallGrades[i]) >= 0) {
                  getGPA += fallGrades[i];

                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(gpa[getGPA]);
```

The reason why `var sum += gpa[getGPA];`  is not working is each time your for loop iterates it will initialize new variable. I have moved outside so it will initialize once and will keep the previous value.

Note: Use `parseFloat` for the float values.

Answer (score 0):

Using `var` inside your loop redeclares it as a local variable within the function scope, rather than using the global `sum` value.

You also don't need to use the inner loop, your code would be more efficient written like the following, note that you need `fullGrades.length-1` as the first element is the semester name.:

```
var sum = 0;
function getGrades(semester){
    if ( semester === "Fall 2015" ){
        for (var i = 1; i < fallGrades.length; i++) { 
            var grade = fallGrades[i];
            sum += gpa[grade];
            console.log( 'letter', grade, 'numeric', gpa[grade], 'current sum', sum );
        }
    }
}
getGrades("Fall 2015");
console.log( 'total sum', sum, 'average', sum/(fallGrades.length-1) );
```

Output

```
letter A- numeric 3.67 current sum 3.67
letter B+ numeric 3.33 current sum 7
letter A numeric 4 current sum 11
letter B numeric 3 current sum 14
letter A numeric 4 current sum 18
total sum 18 average 3.6
```

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I needed and makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @doublesharp "Using var inside your loop redeclares it as a local variable within the function scope", your right about function scope but `redeclares` isn't correct as variable declaration will be hoisted.